# Python- GetProcAddress using ctypes returns NULL

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, ctypes, getprocaddress

**Problem:**

I am trying to get the address of `LoadLibraryW` but gets `NULL`.

**Research effort:**

The function successfully retrieves the `kernel32.dll` address that is mapped to the python process, but returns `NULL` for the `LoadLibraryW` address with *126 error code.*
When I check the function address in process hacker (under the python process) I see a valid address.

```
from ctypes import *
kernel32 = windll.kernel32

def resolve_function(dll, func):
    handle = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA(dll.encode("ascii"))
    address = kernel32.GetProcAddress(handle, func.encode("ascii"))
    kernel32.CloseHandle(handle)
    return address


address = resolve_function('kernel32.dll', 'LoadLibraryW')
print(address)
```

I tried other libraries and other functions but it always returns `NULL`.

Comment: Don't call CloseHandle on a handle you don't own. Set argtypes and restypes on the functions you call. Don't use ASCII, use the Unicode API. Once you've made those changes report back what happens.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks. I changed the function-
def resolve_function(dll, func):
    handle = kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(dll)
    address = kernel32.GetProcAddress(handle, func.encode("ascii"))
    return address
Still returns NULL

Comment: You didn't follow my instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `argtypes` and `restype` attributes on the functions you call so that `ctypes` is able to match the prototypes. I guess this is the main problem in your code.

You should also use the Unicode API as a general rule, in my view. And you must not call `CloseHandle` on the handle returned by `GetModuleHandle`.

Put it all together like so:

```
from ctypes import *
kernel32 = windll.kernel32

def resolve_function(dll, func):
    kernel32.GetModuleHandleW.argtypes = [c_wchar_p]
    kernel32.GetModuleHandleW.restype = c_void_p
    kernel32.GetProcAddress.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_char_p]
    kernel32.GetProcAddress.restype = c_void_p
    handle = kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(dll)
    address = kernel32.GetProcAddress(handle, func)
    return address

address = resolve_function('kernel32.dll', b'LoadLibraryW')
print(address)
```

Answer (score 0):

Listing [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

It looks like an *XY Problem*. 
**You don't need to call any of the 2 functions, *ctypes* does that for you**.

Here's an alternative to your implementation (note that I did no exception handling):

```py
import ctypes


def resolve_function(dll_name, func_name, dll_factory=ctypes.CDLL):
    dll = dll_factory(dll_name)
    return getattr(dll, func_name, None)
```

This is cross platform (will also work on *Nix*).